# Listen to the change of a template variable and display it into the console

Tags: angular

I'm working with angular 7. I'm trying to retrieve the change of a variable value of the template component. Indeed, I declare a variable of boolean type into my .ts file and into the template file its value change after clicking on a button. I want to display this new value on the console. How can I do it please.

I tried double way binding but I'm not working with 2 components but only one and I saw that il works with @Input and @Output so I think it's not possible for me.

Comment: on the onClick() of the button you can change the value and also console it

Comment: show all your code and it may clarify what you're after here.

Comment: You can see the value in the template by adding `<pre>{{value | json}}<pre>` which is sometimes easier then trying to log it.

Comment: Thank you guys ! My problem was  that I didn't use a function for the event binding but just a syntax like : <button (click)='state=!state'>Appuyer</button>. So it was difficult for me to display the "state" variable into the console as I tried to display this variable into the constructor of my .ts file.

Comment: so maybe you want to delete this question? or self-answer it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a function in your ts:

```
changeValue(){
  myBool = !myBool;
  console.log(myBool);
}
```

in your html, add `(click)="changeValue()"` to your button tag.

Comment: Thank you ! My problem was  that I didn't use a function for the event binding but just a syntax like : <button (click)='state=!state'>Appuyer</button>. So it was difficult for me to display the "state" variable into the console as I tried to display this variable into the constructor of my .ts file.

Comment: There is a check mark to the answer's left, click it.